# How to change newline character with one space when concatenating strings in C?

Tags: c, concatenation, newline, fgets, c-strings

Firstly, i must mention that i'm just learning about strings in C as a beginner. 
What i want to do is get 2 strings as input from an user and concatenate them. So here's what i did:

```
char firststring[40], secondstring[40];

printf ("Enter first string: ");
fgets (firststring, 40, stdin);
printf ("Enter second string: ");
fgets (secondstring, 40, stdin);

strcat(firststring, secondstring);
printf("%s", firststring);
```

The problem is that fgets also reads the newline character when the user inputs the first string so the output looks like this:

`Hello
World`

I tried to use `puts` instead of fgets and it worked well, but too many people said NOT to use that function. Then i found out that i can use `strcspn` after the first `fgets` to remove the newline character, but that didn't gave me the one space i want between the words. 
Desired output: `Hello World`
What i got: `HelloWorld`

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thank you so much. I didnt quite understood how strcspn works so i couldnt think of using it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following way

```
printf ("Enter first string: ");
fgets (firststring, 40, stdin);
printf ("Enter second string: ");
fgets (secondstring, 40, stdin);

size_t n = strcspn( firststring, "\n" );
firststring[n] = ' ';
strcpy( firststring + n + 1, secondstring );
```

provided that the firststring has enough space to append the string stored in the array secondstring.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 40 };
    char firststring[N], secondstring[N];

    printf( "Enter first string: " );
    fgets( firststring, N, stdin );

    printf( "Enter second string: " );
    fgets( secondstring, N, stdin );

    size_t n = strcspn( firststring, "\n" );
    firststring[n] = ' ';

    strcpy( firststring + n + 1, secondstring );

    puts( firststring );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter first string: Hello
Enter second string: World!
Hello World!
```

A general approach to remove the new line character from a string entered by a call of `fgets` is the following

```
string[ strcspn( string, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Comment: You might want to make `firststring` larger to avoid potential undefined behavior in `strcpy( firststring + n + 1, secondstring );`

Comment: Thats how i removed the new line initially. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Isn't it better to use `#define N 40` than `enum { N = 40 };`?

Comment: @intmain It is worse because macros do not have scope.